# How to display different datasets from different ajax calls in the same ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, chart.js

I'm trying to display different datasets, from different ajax calls, in the same chartJS.
The idea is to show different stats per month, on 13 consecutive months.
1 ajax call = 1 stat for each of the 13 months.
The JSON data for on stat looks like this :

[{"month":"June 2020","value":0},{"month":"May 2020","value":0},{"month":"April 2020","value":0},{"month":"March 2020","value":0},{"month":"February 2020","value":30},{"month":"January 2020","value":182},{"month":"December 2019","value":143},{"month":"November 2019","value":111},{"month":"October 2019","value":103},{"month":"September 2019","value":128},{"month":"August 2019","value":71},{"month":"July 2019","value":129},{"month":"June 2019","value":98}]

Of course, the values determinate the bars, and the months are the chart's labels.
I can display one stat for every month, but I can't add the others (3 more stats to show).
The expected result : 4 bars for each month.
Here is my working code for one dataset :

```
function getJsonDataForStat1() {
    return $.ajax
    ({
        url: 'getJsonDataForStat1',
        type: 'get'
    });
}


function setChart() {
    $.when(getJsonDataForStat1()).done(function (stats) {

        stats = JSON.parse(stats);
        var data = [], labels = [];

        stats.forEach(function (s) {
            labels.push(s.month);
            data.push(s.value);
        });

        var ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');

        var graph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'stat 1',
                        data: data,
                        backgroundColor: '#735288',
                        borderColor: '#3c8dbc',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }],
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

How to add the 3 others ?
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: In this case you need 4 datasets, one for each statistic. The data array for each dataset would be the values for the different months.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already know that, but I can't get back the data in each different dataset declaration.

Comment: I'll write some sample code generating the datasets when I find a few minutes of time.

Comment: Try creating your graph in a separate function that takes labels and datasets as parameters. Then after each ajax request is finished get the graph and push the datasets into it - `graph.data.datasets.push(yourDataset)`. In your case it is important not to clear previous datasets.

Comment: Thanks Martin M. I've tried your solution but nothing's happening when I try to push the data in the empty graph created just before. Maybe I miss something to make the graph update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you fetched your data and have multiple statistics/arrays containing the data for each month.

You can compute a lookup that maps the month to the values of the different statistics.

The labels are simply the keys, although you'd probably want to sort them based on the date. The datasets can easily be computed by mapping the labels.

```js
var lkp = [stat1, stat2].flat().reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const {
    month,
    value
  } = cur;
  acc[month] = acc[month] || [];
  acc[month].push(value);
  return acc;
}, {});

//{'June 2020': [0, 10], ...}

var labels = Object.keys(lkp).sort((a, b) => (Date.parse(a) % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)) - (Date.parse(b) % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)))
// ['June 2020', 'May 2020']

var colors = ['red', 'green'];

var datasets = [0, 1].map((index) => {
  const data = labels.map(label => lkp[label][index]);
  return {
    data,
    label: `Statistic ${index}`,
    backgroundColor: colors[index],
  }
});

var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels,
    datasets,
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

try {
  new Chart(ctx, options);
} catch (e) {
  //catch co error
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
var stat1 = [{"month":"June 2020","value":0},{"month":"May 2020","value":0},{"month":"April 2020","value":0},{"month":"March 2020","value":0},{"month":"February 2020","value":30},{"month":"January 2020","value":182},{"month":"December 2019","value":143},{"month":"November 2019","value":111},{"month":"October 2019","value":103},{"month":"September 2019","value":128},{"month":"August 2019","value":71},{"month":"July 2019","value":129},{"month":"June 2019","value":98}]
var stat2 = [{"month":"June 2020","value":10},{"month":"May 2020","value":25},{"month":"April 2020","value":75},{"month":"March 2020","value":80},{"month":"February 2020","value":30},{"month":"January 2020","value":182},{"month":"December 2019","value":23},{"month":"November 2019","value":123},{"month":"October 2019","value":50},{"month":"September 2019","value":128},{"month":"August 2019","value":71},{"month":"July 2019","value":129},{"month":"June 2019","value":98}];

</script>
<canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for this sophisticated aswer ! But I still have nothing displaying, it must come from my ajax calls : `function getJsonDataForReceivedAPDDemands() { return $.ajax ({ url: 'getJsonDataForReceivedAPDDemands', type: 'get' }); }       function getJsonDataForOnTimeAchievedPowerUpsRate() { return $.ajax ({ url: 'getJsonDataForOnTimeAchievedPowerUpsRate', type: 'get' }); }      var stat1 = getJsonDataForReceivedAPDDemands();   var stat2 = getJsonDataForOnTimeAchievedPowerUpsRate();`                    How could I write them properly in order to make it work ? (sorry for the presentation)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally succeeded, based on Martin M.'s idea.
Here is my code (maybe it can help someone who has the same issue).
It works perfectly.

```
var graph = setChart();
updateChart();

function setChart() {
    $.when(getData1()).done(function (stats) {

        stats = JSON.parse(stats);

        var data = [], labels = [];

        stats.forEach(function (s) {
            labels.push(s.month);
            data.push(s.value);
        });

        var ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');

        return graph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'data 1',
                        data: data,
                        backgroundColor: '#00c0ef',
                    }],
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}


function updateChart() {
    $.when(setChart()).done(function () {

// I've repeated the following block for data 3 and 4 (still inside updateChart())
        $.when(getData2()).done(function (stats) {

            stats = JSON.parse(stats);
            var data = [];

            stats.forEach(function (s) {
                data.push(s.value);
            });

            var dataset = {};
            dataset.label = "data 2";
            dataset.backgroundColor = '#061834';
            dataset.data = data;

            graph.data.datasets.push(dataset);
            graph.update();
        })
    })
}
```

Thank you all for your help !